# How to call UIScrollView's delegate method when there are two scrollViews in the UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

When there're two scrollViews in the UIViewController, how can I call UIScrollView's delegate method, which makes it only works on one of scrollViews and never affects the another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is not that clear, if you only want to manage one of the `UIScrollViewDelegate`, don't set the `scrollView2.delegate` of the unwanted one.

If you want to different ways of manage of the delegates, here's what you can do, with the example of `scrollViewDidScroll:` method.
Usually, delegates method always give as a parameter the "delegated" object.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == yourScrollView1)
    {
        //Do something
    }
    else //if (scrollView == yourScrollView2)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It's kind of you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All delegate methods in iOS always pass the reference of the calling object, like:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

So use the passed reference for making decision:

```
if([self.scrollView1 isEqual:scrollView])
{
    //Do something here only for scrollview1.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two scrollviews. **scrollA** and **scrollB**. Set tags for both of them

```
scrollA.tag=1;
scrollB.tag=2;
```

and set delegate to both, in the delegate calls handle it like

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(scrollView.tag=1){
         //do something
    }else if(scrollView.tag=2){

    }
}
```

If you don't want to use tags you can easily do like

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
        if(scrollView==scrollA){
             //do something
        }else if(scrollView==scrollB){
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Cheers.